# FXC: Error X3501: 'main': entrypoint not found

Tags: shaders, hlsl

I am trying to compile a vertex shader using VS2013, but every time I try, FXC returns the following error:

> Error error X3501: 'main': entrypoint not found

I've reduced the vertex shader to its simplest form and yet I'm still getting the same result:

**DefaultVS.hlsl**

```
#include "Include.hlsl"

cbuffer CameraTransform {
    float4x4 ViewProjMat;
};

VS_OUT main(VS_IN input) {
    VS_OUT result;

    result.Position = mul(input.Position, mul(input.WorldMat, ViewProjMat));

    return result;
}
```

**Include.hlsl**

```
struct VS_IN {
    float4 Position : POSITION;
    float4x4 WorldMat : INSTANCE_TRANSFORM;
};

struct VS_OUT {
    float4 Position : SV_POSITION;
};
```

And the properties of both files:

> /Zi /E"main" /Od /Fo"Path\To\Output\DefaultVS.cso" /vs"_5_0" /nologo
>
> /Zi /Od /Fo"Path\To\Output\Include.cso" /nologo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is likely VS is trying to compile your `Include.hlsl` file which doesn't actually contain any functions.

Use `Include.hlsli` instead.